# How to insert and retrive a TStringList in a TObjectList

Tags: delphi

I need to save/load many TRichEdit.lines objects to/from a TobjectList and of course save/load to/from a stream and pass back it to the RichEdit.

e.g.

```
ObjList.Add(RichEdit.Lines)
RichEdit.Lines:=TStrings(ObjList[]).....???
```

It does not work in both directions
and how to reload all the ObjList from file/stream ?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 4):

This code looks wrong:

```
ObjList.Add(RichEdit.Lines)
```

Here you are simply taking a reference to the `TStrings` object owned by the rich edit control. Whilst your question title talks about `TStringList`, there is no instance of `TStringList` here.

I presume you mean to take a copy of the strings:

```
var
  Strings: TStringList;
....
Strings := TStringList.Create;
Strings.Assign(RichEdit.Lines);
ObjList.Add(Strings); // assume that ObjList now owns Strings
```

Then in the other direction, your code is already fine:

```
RichEdit.Lines := ObjList[index] as TStrings; 
// this actually copies the content rather than taking a reference to the object
```

But you might want to make the code match that in the other direction:

```
RichEdit.Lines.Assign(ObjList[index] as TStrings);
```

Comment: When a `TStrings`-derived object is passed directly to the `Lines` property, the property setter calls `Assign()` internally.  Also, if you know the `TObjectList` only contains `TStrings` objects, using the `as` operator is overkill since it performs a runtime RTTI lookup.  Using a static type-cast instead is fine: `Lines := TStrings(ObjList[index])` or `Lines.Assign(TStrings(ObjList[index]))`.  If you use `TObjectList<T>` instead of `TObjectList`, you can even get rid of the type-casts altogether.

Comment: @Remy That assignment to `Lines` leads to `Assign` is clear from the code in the second excerpt. My suggestion in the third excerpt is to allow from/to to appear symmetric. `as` is not overkill if you want to pay that price to find errors in your code, perhaps due to maintenance. Same argument applies to range checking. Generic lists would be good, if Delphi version has them.

Comment: Well. Good answer David. But once I saved many TRichEdit.lines objs in a TobjectList, how can I save it in a TFileStream and how to reload in memory?  i.e. TRichEdit ? Thanks

Comment: That's a different question. Many different possible ways. I just answered the question that you asked.